# Simple-looking inequality for Fourier series

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I am looking for a reference (and possibly some history) for the following inequality for finite sums of complex exponentials.

> Let $+\infty>b>a>-\infty$. There exists some constant $C>0$ such that for all $\lambda>0$,
> \begin{equation}
> \sum_{|n|\leqslant\lambda}|a_n|^2 \leqslant C e^{C\lambda}\int_a^b\left|\sum_{|n|\leqslant\lambda}a_n e^{inx}\right|^2dx
> \end{equation}
> holds for all square summable $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbf{Z}}\subset\mathbf{C}$.

Comment: $C$ depending on $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: It will certainly have to since the RHS goes to zero as $b-a\to 0$.